# Image to the first row

Tags: php, mysql, css

Running a mysql query that returns users with their daily highscores.

This is the php file that displays the highscore:

```
<table border="0" width="100%"><?php echo highscore()?>
    </table>
```

This is the php that handles the mysql query (highscore function):

```
echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td>'.$user.'</td><td align="right">'.$score.'</td>';
    echo '</tr>';
```

The mysql query that I have results in the user with the highest score getting on top of the table that you see above.

Now I would like to add a crown to the user that has the most points.

The question is how to add an image(crown.png) to the first row which is the user with the highest score.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Such a vague question. We have no idea what your database looks like, and you've provided only a tiny snippet of code without any context.

Comment: Please, add the complete code of highscore()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you order users by score DESC.

```
$set = 0;
while() {
    echo '<tr';
    echo '<td>';
    if(!$set) {
        echo '<img src="crown.png" alt="crown" />';
    }

    // ... the rest of the code

    $set = 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (empty($notfirst)){
  echo "crown";
  $notfirst=1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i only see a quick and dirty solution, given the code you provide.

I guess you call this code in a loop?

```
echo '<tr>';
echo '<td>'.$user.'</td><td align="right">'.$score.'</td>';
echo '</tr>';
```

so just declare a variable before you start the loop:

```
$first = true;
```

then inside your loop, change your code to:

```
echo '<tr>';
echo '<td>'.$user.'</td><td align="right">'.$score.'</td><td>'.$first?'<img src=\"crown.png\" />':''.'</td>';
echo '</tr>';
$first = false;
```

Comment: Thanks but i get this error: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ';' on the second echo line

Comment: @dreni: i have edited my code. should give no more errors now

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to do this sans PHP you could make your table and use CSS3's new `:first-child` pseudo-selector to add the crown as a background image to the first row.

```
table tr:first-child { background: url("crown.gif") no-repeat; }
```